# Python - map() and list of objects

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

There is a list of objects in the variable games.

```
for g in games:
  if g.clam ==5: g.new_var=1
  if g.clam ==4: g.new_var=0
```

How do I get the above functionality using the map() function? I tried something like the following, but I think it is not close to the right way.

```
def assign_var(clam):
  if clam==5: return 1
  if clam==4: return 0

games.new_var = map(assign_var, games.clam)
```

Comment: You're editing a data structure as you iterate over it. This is not a good idea.

Comment: @EricUrban As long as items aren't added or removed, editing the list should be fine.

Comment: Eric I don't understand your point.  IF I do it in a for loop I'm still iterating over it and editing it.  What am I missing?

Comment: Why do you want to use `map()` here? If you're mutating `games` a simple `for`-loop would suffice. `map` is more suited to creating a new `list` (and even then a list comprehension would be preferred).

Comment: @appleLover If you try to delete an item from a `list` while iterating over it, bad things can happen. In that case you would want to try something else like appending items to a new list.

Comment: As an aside, I would prefer a `dict` (`{4: 0, 5: 1}`) to define the mapping.

Answer (score 1):

Create the new attribute in your `assign_var` function

```
>>> def assign_var(instance):
...     if instance.clam == 5:
...         instance.new_var = 1
...     elif instance.clam == 4:
...         instance.new_var = 0
... 
>>> map(assign_var, games)
[None, None, None] # Intentional. It will modify the list "games" in place.
>>> for ins in games:
...     print ins.new_var
... 
0
1
0
```

But really, this isn't what `map()` should be used for. `map()` should be used for lists that can be returned with changed data, whereas you can't really do that with attributes of a class.

A simple for-loop should be absolutely fine:

```
for ins in games:
    if ins.clam == 5:
        instance.new_var = 1
    elif instance.clam == 4:
        instance.new_var = 0
```

---

Just a little note, remember that *sparse is better than dense* ;).

Comment: "sparse is better than dense" +1 - readability is better than fewer lines.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear why you want to use [`map()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) here. If you're mutating `games` a simple `for`-loop would suffice.

[`map()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) is more suited to creating a new `list` (and even then a list comprehension would be preferred).

I also think a `dict` is a neater way to define the mapping, as it's less bother to maintain. This could be included in your `Game` class.

Here is an example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python


class Game(object):
    clam_to_new_var = {
        4: 0,
        5: 1,
    }

    def __init__(self, clam):
        self.clam = clam

    @property
    def new_var(self):
        return Game.clam_to_new_var.get(self.clam, None)

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Game with clam "{}" has new_var "{}"'.format(
            self.clam,
            self.new_var,
        )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    games = map(Game, xrange(10))
    for g in games:
        print g
```

---

Sample output:

```
Game with clam "0" has new_var "None"
Game with clam "1" has new_var "None"
Game with clam "2" has new_var "None"
Game with clam "3" has new_var "None"
Game with clam "4" has new_var "0"
Game with clam "5" has new_var "1"
Game with clam "6" has new_var "None"
Game with clam "7" has new_var "None"
Game with clam "8" has new_var "None"
Game with clam "9" has new_var "None"
```

I left `map()` in that example, but in production code, I would prefer:

```
games = [Game(clam) for clam in range(10)]
```

Why? See [The fate of `reduce()` in Python 3000](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=98196).